# Overflow of colour bar in saved matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is with regards to the colour bar shown in the picture below. Why is the filling of the colour bar extension overflowing like this? The figure was saved as a PNG with this command:

```
plt.savefig(fname, dpi=300, bbox_inches="tight")
```

This doesn't happen with the default dpi setting, only when I specify higher settings. Any solutions?

[image]

**Code as requested:**

This is a minimum code that reproduces the issue:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = np.random.random((20,20))

ff  = plt.contourf(r, interpolation="nearest" ,extend="both")
cb   = plt.colorbar(ff, format="%3.1f")
cb.solids.set_edgecolor("face")
plt.savefig("test23.png", dpi=400, bbox_inches="tight")
```

And the result:
[image]

Comment: It looks like the linewidth is relatively large on the edge.  From what you have provided (a screen shot) it is impossible to tell if this is a bug in mpl or if it is correctly doing something you did not mean to tell it to do.  Please post a _minimal_ runnable example which demonstrates this.

Comment: That is not what I would call minimal.

Comment: @tcaswell You're right. I've added new code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Yup, looks like a bug.  Can you create an issue on github for this (with the simplified example).  It gets progressively worse at higher dpi.

Comment: Thanks for getting this reduced to a minimal example, it really makes the developer's lives easier.

Comment: Bug report is posted.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `cb.solids.set_edgecolor("face")` was the culprit (cb is the colorer object). Taking it out fixes the problem.

But that leads to another question - with this command why does matplotlib render the way it does? Could this be a bug in its code?

**Edit:**

A bug report has been filed for this.

Comment: Could you give a full working example, so we can look at it a little more?